# Why my system goes in Read-Only file system

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem, read-only

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 3543. My pc sometimes goes into read-only file system. I can check it by opening a terminal and creating a file by `touch a.txt` and its can't create a file and reports "touch a.txt failed: Read-only File system". To fix it, I restart PC and a terminal provided by GRUB appears I put fsck -fy /dev/sda2. It fixes it, but after some processing it again puts the system in read-only. I have also replaced my hard disk, now I am using Kingston SSD, 512 GB, and again facing the same issue.

I want to know why this error persists, and how can I stop it. I only have Ubuntu installed on my PC.

Comment: Check the logs [`dmesg | grep -i 'mount'). Possibly a random hardware error on the MB (since you replaced the disk)(machine i not that new) or a loose connector.

Comment: If errors are detected on a file-system, the *fs* trips to RO to prevent data loss. This occurs because of a problem, be it hardware (failing drive (check SMART), PSU issues where insufficient memory is providing to the computer & thus components are not operating correctly, bad memory, or other type cause), and the *file-system* flipped RO is just the symptom of some error. I'd suggest checking your system, and `fsck` (file system check) your *fs* from *live* media... If it re-occurs, you have issues to solve commonly with the hardware.